# Identify correct guid for diskutil command

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I lost disk space resulting from a failed Boot Camp run.  I was trying to create a partition to run Windows 10.  Bootcamp failed to make the partition, but the allocated drive space disappeared.  This has been covered in another Ask Different thread where I got apartial solution. The command:
 "sudo diskutil cs revert [Logical Volume guid]" 
will recover the space, but I need more details.  See:
[Missing Space on Drive using Core Storage after Boot Camp Assistant Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjfwu.png)

MY QUESTION: I need clarification on the command – What is the right value for [Logical Volume guid]? This could be a dangerous command. Here is my diskutil list:

[image]

I have a MacBook Pro Retina mid-2012, 8gb memory, running High Sierra.

Any help appreciated,
Rolf

Comment: No disk space is missing. The Apple container disk1 reclaims 99.9% of disk0. CoreStorage is **not** enabled on your disk. Instead it's formatted with APFS. You better add the output of `diskutil ap list`!

Answer (score -1):

Answer:  Yes, disk space was in fact missing.  "Get Info" on Macintosh HD came up 30gb short.
**Solution:**  I backed up the whole disk to Time Machine, wiped it, and restored.  Needed some follow-up fixes to things like Google Drive, but all-in-all, it went well.
-Rolf

Comment: **Q: How should I refuel my bicycle? Gasoline or diesel? A: I bought a new car!** Your question doesn't match your answer and vice versa.